# Why was the Trump vandalism answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

This is similar to Nate Eldredges's question about the tax foreclosure question. The answer is [this one](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/58582/4501), deleted by Cesar M. In the tax foreclosure case the OPs account was also deleted (the OP was apparently running a sock puppet farm), but the answerer's account was not deleted here so should we conclude that this is a different cause / person? Perhaps then the answer is "Oops, we meant to delete his account, it is the same sock puppet rancher"; at any rate, it's not a great answer but it's not significantly worse than many noob answers that we get.

Answer (score 2):

I agree and just undeleted that answer.

These deletions seem to have been done at random.  I'm hoping to find time to review all the recent associated deletions; in the meantime feel free to comment on this answer with links to others that don't appear to have merited deletion and I'll look at them promptly.